# Delete a record from connection table when meets a condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a **Customer** model and an **Order** model.
A customer can have multuple orders, and the table to connect between them is **customers_orders** so:

```
Customer >> has_many: orders, :class_name => "CustomerOrders"
```

Until today, I wrote

```
customer.orders.clear
```

in order to delete all orders. It also deleted the records from the connection table.

I added a column to that connection table, lets call it **blah**.
***I want to delete the records from the connection table*** when the blah column has a certain value, so I tried:

```
customer.orders.where("blah = 3").clear
```

But it does not work.

Why? And how can I handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking that you probably want to use a `has many through` here

Assuming something like:

```
class CustomerOrders
   belongs_to :customer
   belongs_to :order
end 

class Customer
  has_many :customer_orders
  has_many :orders, through: :customer_orders
end
```

This way you can get both the actual orders, and the connections, and deal with both individually.

in your example what is `blah` is part of `Order` or `CustomerOrder`

if in CustomerOrder

```
customer.customer_orders.where(blah: 3).destroy_all
```

if in Order

```
customer.customer_orders.where({orders: { blah: 3}}).destroy_all
```

difference between `destroy_all` and `delete_all` has to do with weather or not callbacks are run.

Answer (score 0):

Does a single order also have many customers?

If not, then you do not need a customer_order table -- you just have a customer_id on the order table, and customer has_many orders, and the order belongs to a customer.

Unless customer:order is many:many, you do not need customer_orders